# Android: Continue work from UncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: java, android, android-activity, uncaught-exception

I have set DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler in which i send exception message to server. And after that I want to start base activity, but I need to save all objects states (avoid using System.exit(1)), just start new Intent . Is it possible, if not - why , if yes - how?

Answer (score 0):

An `UncaughtExceptionHandler` doesn't let you rescue the application -- it's there for last-ditch logging. Read the documentation for the class; it mentions quite explicitly that this is invoked immediately prior to the thread terminating.

Comment: What if I change processID to my Base activity ? Then I can Start in from UncaughtExceptionHandler, but anyway I lost all my Objects states. Mb you now how to make objects instances accessible to all proccesses?

Answer (score -1):

What if in tha handler I'll start Base Launch actiovity ?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
```

If I catch exception in first activity - login - this is working ! but if I  start any another activity and there catch exception application just hang with white screen and top bar.

Comment: Add this to question. This is not answering your question.